# How to deactivate all the desktop effects of KDE permanently?

Tags: kde, plasma

I am aware that the shortcode of "Shift + Alt + F12" disables all the desktop effects of Kubuntu 15.10. However, is there a way to disable all those effects automatically and permanently in every future session?

**Objective:** Speeding up Kubuntu 15.10 as much as possible.

Comment: This question is relevant to me because for some reason the autocomplete prompt in IntelliJ idea is also influenced by the fade effect... which is really distracting. I had to disable `Fade` in `Desktop Effects`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Head to

```
System Settings > Hardware > Display and Monitor > Compositor
```

Remove ✔ mark from **Enable compositor on startup**

[image]

When this is done, make reboot.

Comment: +1 - Thank you for your great answer! That indeed is the best way around it.

Comment: I don't think a reboot should be necessary...

Comment: It's not necessary in KDE Plasma 5.16

Comment: When I turned on compositing, it broke the setting window so I couldn't turn it back off again.  

I logged in using gnome/mate, opened `plasma-open-settings` and was able to disable it again.

Answer (score 8):

***EDIT: this answer is for KDE 4 - not 5***

This can be done from:

```
System Settings > Workspace Appearance and Behaviour > Desktop Effects > General > Activation
```

A screenshot to show the menu:

[image]

And a lot of options in there to *selectively* block the effects so you don't miss out on all of the fun :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't manage to find "Workspace Appearance and behaviour" option in the settings but i found the "Desktop Effects" entry. Are those two windows almost identical? (Please check this screenshot for clarification: http://i.imgur.com/KbIKLvx.png). Note: I have installed the KDE desktop environment after installing Ubuntu Mate, so my current installation is not a fresh installation of Kubuntu 15.10.

Comment: That looks like the 'All Effects' tab from my screenshot. Odd...

Answer (score 4):

In openSUSE Leap 42.2 , to turn off desktop effect. click settings > configure desktop> *scroll down to* display and monitor> compositor...un-click enable compositor on start up.